# Spring REST @Validated getting a "JBWEB000065: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I have something like the following in a Spring project:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someRestUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public SomeSo doSomeWork(@Validated @RequestBody SomeSo someSo) {
    ...
}
```

I recently changed SomeSo to have an additional parameter that was required:

```
@NotNull
private String someParameterThatNeedsToBeProvided;
```

Then I promptly left for the evening and when I got back to work the next day, my requests that were working before I made this change were no longer working. It took me forever to figure out why because I can't remember what I did less than 24 hours ago and, more importantly, because the error message sent to the client was only the following with no further details:

[image]

How can I get more information on what the issue is by either logging or sending this information back to the client? Is there some configuration I can do to get either more detailed logging for errors like this (I'd like to NOT include all of Spring's logging at DEBUG level, though) or provide this information to the client?

Note: I'd like to clarify that the request was parseable but was just missing the new parameter. It wasn't poorly formatted JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check out the `Errors` class or the `BindingResult` class. Those give you details on what problems occurred due to `@Validated`. You can include them in the method parameters to interact with them. They are also available to templates. You would want to make a custom error page to output the details of the errors if that is something you want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same error, and it was due to the incoming JSON not matching the object it is being mapped to.

Most probable cause is an empty collection, a single item mapped to a collection or some incorrect data type conversion.

You should enable DEBUG for Spring to detect the failure. Usually this errors are caused by inner exceptions from Jackson Mapper... So take a look at the log to find it, and you'll get an idea of what is the cause for your particular error.